# Как вычислить интервал между now() и date time указанными в таблице

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется запрос sql для создания таблицы в котором имеется столбец `date DATE` и `time TIME`. В запросе sql `SELECT ... FROM table_name` мне нужно получить разницу между данными указанными в таблице и на данный момент времени т.е например дата указанная в таблице `20-12-1999` и время имеющееся в таблице `13:48` и нужно найти разницу между `NOW()` и `20-12-1999 13:48`. Я ориентировался по данной [статье](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/functions-datetime). Если я каким-то образом что-то упустил то ткните носом.

Comment: `select now() - ('2021-01-01' || ' ' || '13:56')::timestamp;`

Comment: т.е в моем sql-запросе это должно выглядеть так `SELECT now() - (date ||  ' ' || time)::timestamp FROM table_name;`

Comment: маловато данных, чтобы ответить однозначно. просто запустите предложенный вами запрос. кстати, если у вас там date и time то правильнее будет написать `('2021-01-01'::date  + '13:56'::time)`

Comment: Да, это помогло мне, спасибо)